# Understanding the derivation of ML-estimator (statistics)

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to understand the derivation of a ML-estimator and more specifically the rewriting of the covariance matrix Sigma. In this rewriting a lemma is used to show that

$$
(1) \hspace{1.4 cm}\Omega=\sigma^2_{c} + \sigma^2_{\varepsilon}I_T=(\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}+T\sigma^2_{c})\boldsymbol{1}(\boldsymbol{1}'\boldsymbol{1})^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}'+\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}(I_T- \boldsymbol{1}(\boldsymbol{1}'\boldsymbol{1})^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}')$$
$$\Omega^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}+T\sigma^2_{c}}\boldsymbol{1}(\boldsymbol{1}'\boldsymbol{1})^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}'+\frac{1}{\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}}(I_t-\boldsymbol{1}(\boldsymbol{1}'\boldsymbol{1})^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}')$$
$$|\Omega|=(\sigma^2_{\varepsilon}+T\sigma^2_{c})\sigma^{{2(T-1)}}_{\varepsilon}$$

1 is a T-vector of ones.

The Lemma states:
[image]

Can anyone explain the second equality in (1)?